# Routing is not working at Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, routes, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I am using routing in one of my asp.net project its not using MVC architecture...
its working at my PC and even at windows server 2003.

below is my code of **global.asax** file:

```
 Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SeoFriendlyUrl") = "true" Then
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.MapPageRoute("HomePage", "", "~/index.aspx", True)
        routes.MapPageRoute("SignUpRoute", "SignUp", "~/Register.aspx", True)
        routes.MapPageRoute("WorkWithUsRoute", "Work-With-Us", "~/WorkWithUs.aspx", True)
        routes.MapPageRoute("AdvertiseWithUsRoute", "Advertise-With-Us", "~/AdvertiseWithUs.aspx", True)
        routes.MapPageRoute("PrivacyRoute", "PrivacyPolicy", "~/PrivacyPolicy.aspx", True)
        routes.MapPageRoute("NewsLetterRoute", "Get-Alerts", "~/NewsLetters.aspx", True)
End Sub
```

I have tried following which i have got while searching for the problem:
**Change in web.config:**

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

**and also :**

```
<system.webServer>    
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">    
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />    
    </modules>    
    <handlers>    
      <add
         name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web,     
          Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    
          PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>    
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And updated my IIS with **Http Redirection**

But Nothing work for me.

Is there any other part which i am missing?

**Edit:**
I am getting following error which is 404 file not found;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to diagnose something like this without being on the machine, it can be so many things...

I'd start with the [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx). This will tell you what routes are hit when a request comes in.

Other possibles could be, .Net is not installed correctly. You'd see an IIS error page when making a request to the site. If IIS is installed after .Net is installed, ASP_net_regiis is not run and ASP.Net is not properly setup. The .Net framework is on the wrong version. You'd think it would just say, "Wrong Version of .Net" but it does not. This might sound stupid, but are you hitting the site at all? Sometimes I get the routes confused and end up thrashing on the wrong site. It takes forever to figure out.

Comment: Are there other ASP.NET sites on this server? I'd try running asp_net_regiis http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx command: aspnet_regiis -i This will ensure ASP.Net 4.0 is installed correctly

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything for over an hour, then I realized I hadn't copied the packages.config file to the live server - Once I did this all the routing worked. without all the web.config and IIS changes.  That one file did the trick for me. Just and FYI for anyone else out there with this problem :D

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should probably put the actual answer at the beginning, otherwise it may seem like you're asking a similar question rather than answering it.  Also, no need for greetings.